# M2E is not for big project?

Tags: eclipse, memory, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I have a java based website that is made of 10 eclipse projects.

```
4 of them contains Entities+DTOs
4 of them contains EJBs+DAOs+services
1 EAR that contains those 8 projects
1 WAR that is made of 20 managed beans and 20 JSF page, along with 12 composite component.
A Jboss As 5.1 server and a tomcat 7 server.
```

The problem is that eclipse is very slow, and it will often do an "out of memory" error and then shut down.
It's running fine on computer with 6GB of ram but computer with 4GB cannot handle it.

I have a friend that has the same environment (eclipse version, jboss version, etc) and it's running fine with 3GB of ram, moreover his project is much bigger than mine.

Only difference is that he is not using M2E.
Instead he has some crazy code in his `pom.xml` copying jar from here to there.
But his pom.xml takes 7h30 to execute `mvn clean install -t4`, mine does it 2 minutes.

Is this a common issue?

Comment: How much of that 4GB/6GB is allocated to Eclipse?  Have you modified eclipse.ini to give it more memory?

Comment: I don't know. I did not do anything to eclipse.ini, but neither did they (those with 6GB computer). therefore it shoudn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend allocating more memory to Eclipse if it's telling you that it's running out.  Add this to your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

You need carriage returns after each line, and I think it should come last in the file.  As to why you are experiencing issues and your friend is not, there's no easy answer.  You guys have different projects and potentially different setups (IDE version, Java version, environment variables, etc.)  I do not think that memory issues related to M2E by itself are common.

Comment: It seems to be working, thanks =D

as for my "friends", they are actually my collegue, we have exactly the same computer (except for the ram, I was suposed to get 6GB to but they were short on ram so I ended up with 4) the same OS, the same maven, the same eclipse, everything is the same xD

(and obviously the same project)

Comment: well even 1024 doesn't seems to be enough, and I can't put more because this is an eclipse 32bit version